# how to import PySimpleGUI in vscode using python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

actually i have a problem. I want to import PySimpleGUI in vscode. but when i install pip with **`pip install PySimpleGUI`** i get following error:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x00000269E2A0A160>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out.
> (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pysimplegui/

Do know someone what i'm doing wrong and how i can correctly install that?

Comment: Please close unnecessary processes and reload VSCode, then reinstall the module "PySimpleGUI".

Answer (score 1):

Try loading Pypi.org if that works that its an underlying issue but normally this happens if the site is having trouble, other times even your DNS, but a big one i've heard is being connected to a VPN so if you're connected to a VPN disconnect from it and try again.

Comment: yeah thank you very much... or i could add --user --proxy=http://MyProxy also something like that **pip install PySimpleGUI --user --proxy=http...** and the a upgrade like **pip -m upgrade pip --proxy=...**